# Adding spotlight effect on an object in the scene using three.js

Tags: animation, three.js, spotlight

I'm trying to add a spotlight effect on different parts of my scene but for some reason I'm unable to accomplish it. I tried using `PointLight` and `SpotLight` but they both didn't work.

Example of the code

```js
 var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 10 );
 pointLight.position.set(obj.position);
 scene.add( pointLight );
```

The light effect doesn't need to follow the mouse movement. It just needs to appear after specific event trigger.

I'm not sure if the spotLight or the pointLight is the right way to do this.
I appreciate any feedback on what approach I should take and what is the best way to accomplish this animation.

Attempted adding `SpotLight` like so

```js
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(  0xffffff );
spotLight.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );

spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 512;
spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 512;
spotLight.target = obj;
spotLight.intensity = 2;
scene.add( spotLight );

var spotLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( spotLight );
scene.add( spotLightHelper );
```

[image: Animation example]

Comment: Are you searching for [`SpotLight`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/SpotLight)?

Comment: I'm looking for something that would accomplish the animation in the gif. My first thought was to use `SpotLight` or `PointLight` but they both didn't work.

Comment: What have you tired so far. Of course you can't just switch on a spot light. You have to animate the light intensity and the light cone.

Comment: I started by just adding the `SpotLight` to the scene and that didn't work. I added the code to the original post.

Comment: The SpotLight code I added to the question portion.

Comment: I've seen that. But what "did not work"? "Did not work" is not a technical description of an issue.

Comment: I mean that the SpotLight didn't even show up on my scene.